# How to add a Leaflet Map with specific coordinates through an API request?

Tags: ajax, api, leaflet, coordinates

I set the following callback function to get the coordinates of some specific city, according to which is the string typed into a text field:

```
var readCoordinates = function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent($("#inlineFormInputCitta").val()) + "+Italy&format=geocodejson",            
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            setTimeout(function () {

                for (let i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    let coordinate = data.features[i];

                    $("#tbody2").append("<tr><td>" + coordinate.geometry.coordinates + "</td></tr>");                                                  

                };

            }, 1000);
        }
    });

};
```

I want to add a Leaflet Map to display the map of the city, according to which are the coordinates I get through the callback function.
I add the following `<div>` into my HTML code:

```
<!-- using Leaflet library for free, step 1: create a </div> -->
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
```

And then I added the following lines of code to the previous snippet:

```
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
                        center: [0, 0],
                        zoom: 0,
                        layers: [
                            new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                                'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            })
                        ]
                    });
```

What I get on my webpage is the following:

[image: Map]

How should I do to insert the right coordinates into my lines of code, in order to have the map of the specific region I need?

- - - - - -EDITED - - - - -

I changed my code because I initialized the map undo the Ajax call (thank you for pointing out). I cut and paste the snippet above outside the Ajax call instead, by creating a new function `initMaps()` :

```
function initMaps(){

    map = L.map('leaflet').setView([0, 0], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

}
```

The problem is to reset the coordinates under the Ajax call function now, but I don't see that error anymore.

Comment: You have a pretty specific error there, `Map container is already initialized`. How many times are you calling `L.map()` or `new L.Map()`? I see only once in the code you posted here, so please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Also, think whether you want to create a map or reset the view of an already-existing map instance.

Comment: I called 'L.map() ' once...

Comment: @franz1 seems like you initialize your map at every AJAX call. As to how to change a map view, look for Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group, getBounds and fitBounds.

Answer (score 1):

1. if you see random squares of map, like I see on your screenshot, it probably means that you didn't load the **leaflet css** properly
2. Like it was said in the comments, if you call `new L.Map` at **every ajax call**, then you initialize the map more than once and you get the error.
3. So, initialize your map once (outside the ajax call) and then add some data to your initialized map. Usually a new Layer, or a GeoJson. At each call, you will have to clean the previous layers first, and then create some new ones.